# Working with ListView

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-developer-api

I am working with a ListView. I want to change the text color of my ListView text "Basic Requirement"

```
<string name="app_name">Easy Excel</string>
<string name="search">search</string>
<string-array name="Formula_name">
    <item>Basic Requirement</item><!--I want to text color red-->
    <item>Funny message</item>
    <item>Festival message</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer from here:

> You can not directly tell the (array) resource which color it should
>   have. You either can define an app-wide theme/style to use for list
>   items or create an Adapter with custom view.

[how to change the color of string array resources in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26360454/how-to-change-the-color-of-string-array-resources-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom adapter and then override the getview method and put in the following piece of code.

```
if(position == 0) {
    row.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
}
else{
 row.setBackgroundColor (Color.WHITE); 
}
```